# I have used this command npm run eject it's not working

Tags: reactjs

```
npm run eject

npm ERR! path C:\Users\sudarshan\Desktop\React\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\sudarshan\Desktop\React\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.       
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sudarshan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-05T11_05_36_102Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Is the file there? Where did you run the command from? You should add more info and how you have tried to debug it

Comment: Are you into the correct folder?

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize the project with `npm init`?